# Intel Graphics Drivers - Hue issues?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I'm running Windows XP SP3.

The embedded graphics controller is the Intel GM45 Chipset / Mobile Intel 4 Series Express.

The OEM drivers (it's a Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop) are provided only up to 6.14.10.4990 (Dell driver code R203389).

I usually like to stick with OEM drivers on Dell stuff, since they often have tweaked it for the specific machine. But I needed to run an app that refused to run on the old video driver (it's dated 2009). So I went to Intel's site, downloaded the newest driver (6.14.10.5355), and installed it.

It's working fine except...the screen seems a little "warmer" than usual. I.e., my whites seems slightly reddish. Oh, its ever so slight, in fact my friend was unable to confirm, but then he doesn't look at this screen every day.

Its not enough that its 100% conclusive but it definitely seems to be a little warmer. However the gamma/hue corrections do not seem to have changed, at least the driver panel reports them the same. I'm not using any gamma profiles of any sort, just default (what you get, or don't get, with a clean XP install).

I noticed the new drivers have the ability to customize gamma on a per-color basis (RGB), while the old drivers simply had a master gamma. The new driver also allows the gamma to be set below 1.0 (previous drivers didn't). Nonetheless, all the settings still appear to be the same as before the upgrade: (Brightness: 0, Contrast: 50, Gamma: 1.0).  (zero brightness is more or less centered on the slider, so it seems to be the way the driver labels the midpoint.)

Is it possible the screen is actually "warmer" with the new drivers? Or am I just imagining things? Is there any way I can test it? Preferably without buying extra fancy gizmos.

**Example: I turn down the Red brightness to the point where whites look bluish, yet human skin in a photo still looks more reddish-pink than it does with the old drivers.**

Comment: It's possible.  Testing?  Good luck unless you can screenshot with some hardware device that seems like a monitor.

Comment: There was another question on here recently complaining of off colors on Intel graphics, and while I can't seem to find it here that user did some research and apparently found that the colors being off is a common complaint (his was too blue, if I recall...)

Comment: Same problem, too warm white on sony vaio. On mac there is a separate control for the color temperature, but how can I adjust on intel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very possible to have your screen colors mess up on you. However, the only was to test the colors is fairly subjective. You can try the [Lagom Monitor Tests](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/) to see if they can make a problem apparent. in particular the [Lagom LCD Gamma Calibration](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/gamma_calibration.php) test page may be able to help you discern if this color change is real or only a feeling.

On the other hand, what does it matter if it IS warmer if it FEELS warmer. This is not an ethical or moral issue, so follow your preference. It's your monitor and the way the picture feels to you matters more than a test. I'm somewhat color-blind in the reds and greens, but it affects pretty much entirely how I see all colors. I have my monitor set up so that it displays closer to how I actually perceive the world. Even if the monitor isn't warmer, if it feels warmer, turn it down.

Sorry, that got kind of philosophical, but hopefully that website helps concretely.

Comment: @UnsignedCodeLabs Oh I see: I don't think I can help you then. Maybe rollback and figure out how to the the app working with the old drivers? Sorry.

Comment: @UnsignedCodeLabs I meant the app that forced you to upgrade. I realize the color issues are system-wide with the new driver. Have you contacted Dell about a solution? I doubt they'll have anything but you never know if they *might* help.

Comment: Sorry that it didn't get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree, I observe the same thing on my Intel HD 3000 graphics: the colors are far more bright than with my previous graphics card, the image is almost "burnt". I have to decrease brightness to 80-85% to obtain "normal" colors.