# Alternative to intel control panel with greater brightness range?

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio, brightness

My Intel control panel allows the brightness to be set to a minimum of only 40. Is there a way to allow a broader setting range?

I am using Windows 7 and a Sony Vaio 64-bit box.

Lowering the brightness usually helps when the color is too warm. Unfortunately I didn't find
setting where I can adjust the color temperature (The mac has one). See also: 
[Intel Graphics Drivers - Hue issues?](https://superuser.com/questions/337784/intel-graphics-drivers-hue-issues)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a limitation of the driver, but if it is actually a limit of the software, then you can indeed try other tools. One good one is Nirsoft’s [`NirCmd`](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). You can use it from the command-prompt like this:

```
nircmd changebrightness 10
nircmd changebrightness -5
```

The first command increases brightness by 10 and the second decreases it by 5 (don’t ask what units they are, nobody knows).